# Building a rails app for white-labeling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, white-labelling

I'm curious how you would create an rails 3 app that makes it easy to white label it.  For example if you had a site that did reviews of food and a site that did reviews movies what is the best way to customize the routes so /foods works on one site and /movies works on the other.  Obviously some sort of config but what about if it isn't set, it should probably fallback to /reviews.

On a smaller scale I can kind of wrap my head around this problem but I'm curious how this scales up to say 100 sites.  Where you can't really store all their configs in the same git repo and what do you do about custom ways of creating a reviewable model.  Since foods and movies aren't going to have the same params and if you let users enter them in there has to be some sort of customization for that.

Additionally i'm guessing each site probably should be self contained in some way to prevent a problem with one site bringing down the rest of them.

I think I'm only scratching the surface here and I haven't been able to find any articles talking about this kind of stuff.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=multi-tenant+rails

Comment: Guess I was asking the wrong question, thanks!